# Getting AJAX to work in PhoneGap

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, cordova

Right now I need to use phonegap to call on a php script on another webserver  to retrieve data from a database i have. Running the script with hard codes retrieves the data correctly but it appears as tho either the ajax call is not returning anything or not even getting the data as post. Currently in the console I am getting `"Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. "`

```
    $(document).ready(function() {      
       $('.check').click(function(){
       alert("Step1");
       var thisID    = $(this).attr('id');
       alert(thisID);

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "http://csmaster.sxu.edu/group2/group2/CougarLunch/retrieveColumn.php",
           data: { ID: thisID},
           cache: false,
           async:true,
           datatype: "json",
           success: function(data)
               {
             console.log(data);
             alert(data.ItemID);
              }

          });
          }); 
          });
```

PHP if it is relevent I doubt it tho

```
    if(isset($_POST['ID']))
      {
       $ID = $_POST['ID'];
       function retrieve($ID)
         {
          $stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM  group2.menu  WHERE ItemID = $ID");

          if($stmt->num_rows) //if there is an ID of this name
            {  
              $row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
              echo $row;
              print json_encode($row);  

           }
        }
```

Comment: When it's an actual app on the phone, you shouldn't be restricted by the cross domain policy.

Comment: 1 Why is that? 
2. It already isn't working when I launch it in chrome so I'm dubious about that.

Comment: See these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641442/phonegap-jquery-ajax-cross-domain-requests-work-in-browser-fail-in-android-sdk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920782/phonegap-javascript-sending-cross-domain-ajax-request http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363005/mobile-apps-cross-domain-ajax

Comment: have you white listed the domain in phonegap config?

Comment: Just a word of caution about this code `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*");` because it essentially opens up your PHP file to be run by absolutely any AJAX request so in theory I can write an AJAX call from my website to yours and access whatever data is available on that URL. I recommend messing around with `console.log(document.URL);` and see if you can narrow down the URL/domain that PhoneGap might emulate. Try it from different phones, tables, networks, wifi on/off, etc.

Comment: right now I'm just trying to get it to work in chrome, I have input an else statement to send a default json just to check and it appears as tho the post is never getting sent or received properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to the top of php file to allow access:

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*");
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
```

[phonegap doc](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html)